# Ruby Metaprogramming: dynamic instance variable names

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, instance-variables

Let's say I have the following hash:

```
{ :foo => 'bar', :baz => 'qux' }
```

How could I dynamically set the keys and values to become instance variables in an object...

```
class Example
  def initialize( hash )
    ... magic happens here...
  end
end
```

... so that I end up with the following inside the model...

```
@foo = 'bar'
@baz = 'qux'
```

?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`instance_variable_set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set). So:

```
hash.each { |name, value| instance_variable_set(name, value) }
```

Or, more briefly,

```
hash.each &method(:instance_variable_set)
```

If your instance variable names are missing the "@" (as they are in the OP's example), you'll need to add them, so it would be more like:

```
hash.each { |name, value| instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value) }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me for 1.9.3. I used this instead `hash.each {|k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}",v)}`

Comment: yet another reason to love Ruby

Comment: can you please explain how in `hash.each &method(:instance_variable_set)`, the method `instance_variable_set` receives the two parameters that it needs?

Comment: any idea how to do this recursively ? (if there is multiple level in the input hash)

Answer (score 16):

```
h = { :foo => 'bar', :baz => 'qux' }

o = Struct.new(*h.keys).new(*h.values)

o.baz
 => "qux" 
o.foo
 => "bar"
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting... what exactly is the second chained `.new()` doing?

Comment: @Andrew: `Struct.new` creates a new class based on the hash keys, and then the second `new` makes the first object of the just-created class, initializing it to the values of the Hash.  See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Struct.html

Comment: This is actually a really great way to do it since this is pretty much what Struct is made for.

Comment: Or use [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html). `require 'ostruct'; h = {:foo => 'foo'}; o = OpenStruct.new(h); o.foo == 'foo'`

Comment: I had to map my keys to symbols: `Struct.new(*hash.keys.map { |str| str.to_sym }).new(*hash.values)`

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `send` which prevents the user from setting non-existent instance variables:

```
def initialize(hash)
  hash.each { |key, value| send("#{key}=", value) }
end
```

Use `send` when in your class there is a setter like `attr_accessor` for your instance variables:

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :foo, :baz
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each { |key, value| send("#{key}=", value) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You make we want to cry :)

In any case, see [`Object#instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001028) and [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001029).

Happy coding.

Comment: er yes, i couldn't help wondering... why? when would be a good time to use this?

Comment: for example, I might want to have a generic `set_entity` callback for all controllers, and I don’t want to interfere with existing instance variables `def set_entity(name, model); instance_variable_set(name, model.find_by(params[:id])); end;`