# Initializing a variable RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-variables

I have a class Sample

Sample.class returns

```
(id :integer, name :String, date :date)
```

and A hash has all the given attributes as its keys. 
Then how can I initialize a variable of Sample without assigning each attribute independently.

Something like

```
Sample x = Sample.new

x.(attr) = Hash[attr]
```

How can I iterate through the attributes, the problem is Hash contains keys which are not part of the class attributes too

Comment: Why would the attributes be keys and not values?  I'm a bit lost on that.

Comment: I have a hash which has the attributes as a key so that i can map the name of the attribute with the hash key and then assign s.attr the value

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. This may be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Sample
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :date
end

h = {:id => 1, :name => 'foo', :date => 'today', :extra1 => '', :extra2 => ''}

init_hash = h.select{|k,v| Sample.method_defined? "#{k}=" }

# This will work
s = Sample.new
init_hash.each{|k,v| s.send("#{k}=", v)}

# This may work if constructor takes a hash of attributes
s = Sample.new(init_hash)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article on Object initialization](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/objinitialization.html). You want an `initialize` method.

EDIT You might also take a look at [this SO post on setting instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741567/ruby-metaprogramming-dynamic-instance-variable-names), which I think is exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to iterate through the attributes for the inizialization. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sure, you might save their names to a class variable (i.e. an array like `@@attrs = [:id, :name, :date]`) and loop over them later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :z
end

a = A.new
my_hash = {:x => 1, :y => 2, :z => 3, :nono => 5}
```

If you do not have the list of attributes that can be assigned from the hash, you can do this:

```
my_attributes = (a.methods & my_hash.keys)
```

Use `a.instance_variable_set(:@x = 1)` syntax to assign values:

```
my_attributes.each do |attr|
  a.instance_variable_set("@#{attr.to_s}".to_sym, my_hash[attr])
end
```

Note(Thanks to Abe): This assumes that either all attributes to be updated have getters and setters, or that any attribute which has getter only, does not have a key in my_hash.

Good luck!

Comment: Might want to test that with an `attr_reader :nono` in the class definition ;)

Comment: @AbeVoelker `my_attributes = (a.methods & my_hash.keys)` does it.

Comment: `attr_reader :nono` will create a `nono` (reader) method, but not a `nono=` (writer) method.  `my_attributes = (a.methods & my_hash.keys)` is only checking for reader methods.  Should attributes be assigned that don't have writer methods?

Comment: @AbeVoelker Good point. I guess Dave Newton will have to select based on his needs. I am editing my response to reflect this consideration.